# Internal server error when uploading pdf using php

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

I am uploading 6 pdf files using PHP form but I am getting

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time
>   the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have
>   caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

When I am uploading only one pdf it will uploaded successfully.

My each pdf size is approx 10-15 mb.

can any one please tell me what may cause issue.

I have already set max_execution_time = 111111111111111111;

max_input_time = 11111111111;

memory_limit = 128M;

max_upload_size =200M;

Can any one please help me to resolve this problem?

this is my form :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally, a 500 status code (Internal Server Error) leaves a trace in the web server logs. Look there first.

Comment: posting the code may also help, can you check logs and make sure you have proper permissions such as permission to write in the upload folder

Comment: @kumar : when i am uploading single it uploading proper but when i am going to upload 3 files, it gives me an internal server error. i am attaching my form snap. Please have a look on it

Comment: @Sanjay ji, sharing the PHP code will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

And how is your webserver configured for timeouts, max request size, max post size etc?

Comment: i put php.ini on server root and its working proper using ftp details

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to use MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden attribute for POST request?

`<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000000">`

Note that it must precede the file input field. It is in bytes, so this will limit the upload to 20MB. See [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for details.